# Failed to compile hello world with clang-11 built from source code

Tags: c++, docker, clang, llvm

I built llvm+clang+lld from source code in a docker container.

```
% CC=$HOME/toolchains/bin/gcc CXX=$HOME/toolchains/bin/g++ \
cmake …/llvm -G “Unix Makefiles” \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=“clang;lld” \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel \
-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=“X86” \
 -DCMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,$HOME/toolchains/lib64 -L$HOME/toolchains/lib64"

% make -j && sudo make install
```

Then I try to compile a hello world program with clang, and I got the error message:

```cpp
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf(“hello\n”);
  return 0;
}
```

```
% clang test.c
error: unknown target CPU 'x86-64’
```

Are there something wrong with my building process?

The llvm version is 11.0.0 release.

The version of gcc under $HOME/toolchains is 5.2.0.

My docker version is:

```
Client:
Version: 17.06.2-ce
API version: 1.30
Go version: go1.8.3
Git commit: e046fc5
Built: Tue Oct 17 02:06:56 2017
OS/Arch: linux/amd64

Server:
Version: 17.06.2-ce
API version: 1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version: go1.8.3
Git commit: e046fc5
Built: Tue Oct 17 02:09:18 2017
OS/Arch: linux/amd64
Experimental: false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LLVM & Clang can't compile for a supported arch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944340/llvm-clang-cant-compile-for-a-supported-arch)

Comment: No, actually it's not a cross compiling.