# Is there a difference between Apple Clang and OpenMP-enabled Clang from Homebrew?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, openmp

I want to know if there are any advantages in Apple's provided Clang compiler compared to the Clang compiler that comes with OpenMP available from Homebrew?
Will there be any performance loss if switching to OpenMP Clang (regardless of the multi-threading ability)?

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665744/what-is-the-difference-between-clang-and-apple-clang) old question that has no good answer

---

### Update

I compiled the [OOFEM](https://github.com/oofem/oofem) using Apple's Clang and mainstream Clang and ran the same problem,

Apple's Clang: Real time consumed: 000h:01m:26s

Mainstream Clang: Real time consumed: 000h:01m:24s

With multi-threading enabled also the performance is similar.
One difference that I also noticed, is that Apple's Clang seems to ignore some CMake options e.g. `-DOpenMP_CXX_FLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include"` has no effect with Apple's Clang while works fine with the mainstream Clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a difference?

As stated that answers itself. They're two different compilers and we don't know what Apple have done inside theirs. We do know that they don't provide OpenMP support, so that is at least one difference.

> Will there be any performance loss if switching to OpenMP Clang
> (regardless of the multi-threading ability)?

I doubt it, but since you're clearly measuring performance and playing with both compilers, you seem in a good position to tell us :-)

Comment: Jim, do you have any up-to-date reference saying that apple clang still does not support OpenMP?
I am using -fopenmp flag and it seems Apple Clang is happy with it, if it didn't support OpenMP shouldn't it have nagged about that?

Comment: The fact that they do not ship the OpenMP runtime is itself enough to say that they are not supporting OpenMP :-) iIt hould be easy to check whether the compiler itself handles OpenMP by looking at the asm output. (If I weren't on my phone in a park, I'd look!)

Comment: When I try to pass the -fopenmp flag to Apple's clang it is rejected
`$ /usr/bin/clang -fopenmp -v -s hello_omp.c`
`Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)`
`Target: arm64-apple-darwin20.6.0`
`Thread model: posix`
`InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`
`clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'`

Comment: I think you should use -Xpreprocessor before -fopenmp for Apple's Clang

Comment: Yup, with `-Xpreprocessor -fopenmp` Apple's clang (`Apple clang version 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)`) does pass -fopenmp to the compiler itself and does generate OpenMP runtime calls. However, since they don't ship `<openmp.h>` or the runtime library, they clearly do not support OpenMP. (And, as we have seen, getting those installed and found [including at runtime] is non-trivial). So my conclusion remains: Use brew to install a real clang (or GCC, come to that).